# Why does onsubmit function seem not to execute?

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. validateForm() does not seem to execute from an onsubmit. Here is validateForm()

```
function validateForm() {
    var amt = IsNumeric(document.forms["InvGenPay"]["Amount"].value);

    alert(amt);

    if (amt == false)
    {
        alert("placeholder to avoid scrolling.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function IsNumeric(strString)
{
    //  check for valid numeric strings  
    var strValidChars = "0123456789.";
    var strChar;
    var blnResult = true;

    if (strString.length == 0) return false;

    //  test strString consists of valid characters listed above
    for (i = 0; i < strString.length && blnResult == true; i++)
    {
        strChar = strString.charAt(i);
        if (strValidChars.indexOf(strChar) == -1)
        {
            blnResult = false;
        }
    }

    if (0 > parseFloat(strString))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return blnResult;
    }
}
```

Here is the form with onsubmit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2">
document.write('<form name="InvGenPayDonation" action="'+PostURL+'" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST">');
</script>


<input type='text' name='DonationAmount' value="0.00">
In honor of <span style="color: #FF0000"><br />
<input type='text' name='TransDesc' id='TransDesc' value="" >
<input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you writing your opening form tag with a document.write line?

Comment: Why are you document.write the form tag? If you need to set the action, do it with code. `document.InvGenPayDonation.action = PostURL;`

Comment: Where are you defining `PostURL`?

Comment: Why are you `document.write`-ing your `<form>`?

Comment: Yeah, you can't actually do that with a Javascript statement, there has to be `string..." +` or a line continuation character (which I think is shabbily supported, I don't use it). Also, *please*, **please** do not do this to your page. `document.write` is horribly outdated and I suggest you should learn newer methodologies.

Comment: I'm writing it to form an outgoing URL based on an incoming URL. It's a form of web routing we use. The form works, but the onsubmit does not.

Comment: `method=POST` should be `method="POST"`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "it works". It's severely out of date (no offense). There's so many better, more adaptable and "robust" ways of doing this. I'd also say, some are kinda fun.

Comment: @Rocket not in HTML5 - quotes are optional if the value has no whitespace or equals signs.

Comment: I've edited the OP to take into account these comments. I'd prefer to remove the document.write and assign the action directly.

Comment: See [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) (`window.attachEvent` on IE8 and lower). Consider this an intervention. `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that you don't have the right form name (or the right field name for that matter) in your validation code.

```
var amt = IsNumeric(document.forms["InvGenPay"]["Amount"].value);
```

vs

```
'<form name="InvGenPayDonation" action="'+PostURL+'"
```

Full, working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"         
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
  <title>Sampe file</title>

  <script>
function validateForm() {
    // Badly named variable, since this is actually a boolean of 'IsNumeric'
    var amt = IsNumeric(document.forms["InvGenPayDonation"]["DonationAmount"].value);


    // Can be simplified as simply:
    //return amt;
    alert('Amt = ' + amt);

    if (!amt)
    {
        alert("placeholder to avoid scrolling.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function IsNumeric(n) {
  // Shamelessly stolen from: 
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

</script>

<body>
<form name="InvGenPayDonation" action="#"
        onsubmit="return validateForm();" 
        method=POST>


<input type='text' name='DonationAmount' value="0.00">
In honor of <span style="color: #FF0000"><br />
<input type='text' name='TransDesc' id='TransDesc' value="" >
<input type="submit" value="Next">

<script>
  // Assigned for testing purposes
  var  PostURL = "#"
  document.forms.InvGenPayDonation.action = PostURL;
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually the biggest issue is the unescaped new lines in the `document.write` string. This is the second biggest :-P

Comment: Oops -- Had to fix `onsubmit="return validateForm();" `  That was left a bit weird from my debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have un-escaped newlines in a JavaScript string.  Check your JavaScript console, you are probably getting a syntax error.  That error is why the `onsubmit` is not running.

Also, as suggested, do not use `document.write`, just write the form normally in HTML, and use JavaScript to add *just* the POST url.

```
<form name="InvGenPayDonation" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST">
    <input type='text' name='DonationAmount' value="0.00">
    In honor of <span style="color: #FF0000"><br />
    <input type='text' name='TransDesc' id='TransDesc' value="" >
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms.InvGenPayDonation.action = PostURL;
</script>
```

P.S. As [Jeremy J Starcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12396359/206403) pointed out, your form name is wrong inside `validateForm`.

Comment: I compressed this so it wouldn't scroll.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Huh?  So what wouldn't scroll?

Comment: I've edited the OP and replaced the document.write without breaking lines to avoid scrolling.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Then your code should work, though you need to check the form name inside `validateForm`.

Comment: I take comments seriously here, which is why I extracted the document.write comments and asked a separate question. I changed the form name, and it still does not fire.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Don't ask a separate question.  Was your question not answered here yet?  Update it, don't ask a new one.

Comment: The initial question was answered.